# How do I say "nowadays" in Esperanto?

Tags: translation

In my three primary languages there is one word for this concept: "nowadays", "heutzutage", "nuförtiden". How do I say this in Esperanto? I think "nuntempe" means "now", so I don't think it covers the meaning of "in our time" - "en niaj nunaj tempoj"? I'd like to throw in a "kutime" there, too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The expression "nuntempe" does have the meaning of "nowadays" and "heutzutage". If you just want to say "now", you say "nun". It might not be completely logical, but it has acquired this fixed meaning already long ago, and is used by practically everyone in this sense.

Comment: Thank you! Not sure how I misunderstood this, but it's great to know now.

Answer (score 6):

JC Wells gives *nun(temp)e* for *nowadays*. He's got *nun* as *now*, so either *nune* ("at the time of now") or *nuntempe* seems adequate for *nowadays*, or *in this time*. But I'm still just a *komencanto*.

Answer (score 4):

I think *nuntempe* is often used in both senses - 'right now' as well as 'nowadays'. I would like to think that using it in the sense of 'right now' is erroneous because it creates ambiguity and there are already other ways to express this (*nune*, *ĝuste nun*), however I'm aware that many people use it in this sense. If you search for *nuntempe* in [tekstaro.com](http://tekstaro.com) it appears that the majority of the uses are in the sense of 'nowadays'.

A possible alternative could be *nunepoke*. I think the meaning here is clear and there is no ambiguity, however I haven't been able to find it in the dictionaries and it only appears in Tekstaro once.

Comment: Nunepoke is a great solution! That really covers the meaning of our time as in the period of history we live in.